# При билде проекта на Angular9, проходит все пункты, кроме теста(сам билд успешно проходит)

Tags: angular, token, toast

Есть проект на Angular - версии 9.0.3
Есть ngx-toastr - версии 13.0.0
При билде проекта не проходит тест(при этом проект спокойно проходит пункт билд)
Выдаёт следующие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: следующий есть ли решение данной проблемы?
app.module.ts:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
test.ts:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так ты покажи файл тестов, зачем AppModule? =)

Comment: Добавил правку в вопрос

Comment: во 1х не вставляй картинки. во 2х файл с тестами = .spec.ts файлы. Мне кажется или ты забежал очень сильно вперед не изучив основы? =))

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек за советы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо большое overthesanity, знайте героя в лицо, на деле все оказалось просто, так как я не шарю в тестах, то и соответственно не добавил в тест импорт своего тоста, после же все заработало, ещё раз большое спасибо за советы и направление на верный ответ -> overthesanity, где тут лайк поставить?)